# Angular: HTML page finishes rendering before images are loaded from backend

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-resolver

I'm programming a website that displayes some products and each product has an image.
For this I have to do 2 things: 1.) load the products from backend. 2.) load the images from backend.

[image: current state]

Right now the images don't get shown, because while loading the images from the backend, the HTML View already gets rendered / build up. At that time the images are not there, yet. When I had more products, the further down products had their images properly displayed.

I read that the preferred solution is to use a route resolver to pre load the images before rendering the component, so I implemented a Product Resolver Service :

```
export class ProductResolverService implements Resolve<any> {

map = new Map();

constructor(private _data: DataService, private router: Router) { }
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
return this._data.getProducts().pipe(map(myProducts => {     //getProducts() loads all product from the database and returns an Observable<Product[]>

  myProducts.forEach(myProduct => {
    //takes the myProduct and loads the image as a BLOB from backend. Then puts that blob into this.map.
    this.loadMainProductPicture(myProduct);
  })
  return this.map;
}),
  catchError(e => {
    console.error(e);
    this.router.navigate(['users']); // the rerouting worked when I put an error on purpose in the part above
    return null; 

  }))
}
```

And in my component I run following code to get the just preloaded images:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.map = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['map'];
  console.log(typeof(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['map']))  // object
  console.log(this.map);
  console.log(this.map.size);                                    // 0

  this.loadProducts();  //load all products from the database again (This works and has nothing to do with the images, I just didn't know how to return the products and the images from the Product Resolver Service, so I decided to only return the images and then load the products again here.
}
```

And in my app-routing.module.ts I added this to the routes:

`path: '', component: ProductsComponent, resolve: { map: ProductResolverService }`

The loading of the image blobs kinda works, the blobs are there, but they come as an Object, not a Map. You can see the three logs from the `console.log` commands in `OnInit()`:

[image: my console logs]

**Now my problem is how to access the blobs from that object?** If I could access the blobs, I can put them in my function createImageFromBlob(blob) and then display them, this worked before. But I just don't get the blobs out of the object.

And also, this is super complicated already, and a bit messy with. This must be a problem many people face, isn't there a better solution to load the images?

**EDIT:** I'm using Java Spring Boot as backend and store the images locally in seperate folders for each product. The filename of each image I save with the product in my SQL Database. So when loading the image to a product, I first need to load the image filename from the database and then I can load the image from the local storage.

[image: my image folders in backend]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using Blobs, why not just serve paths to images like "https://your-site.com/imgs/vw-polo.jpg"?
Can you provide any more info about your task and your backend?

Comment: That would probably be a good idea, but I store my images locally and don't have them accessible via URL. Maybe I should upload them at the beginning to a hidden sub-url of my page and then take them from there each time I need them? But that doesn't sound like a good solution either. ps. I added an edit with info about my backend at the end of my question now.

Comment: you just create a folder named 'images' and store files named like 'product_1', 'product_2' etc.

Comment: sorry, but I don't think that works. On the frontend side I can't create folders with the images, I would need to download them on the users pc / phone, no?